# Apache Solr : Search is not returning result for large document indexed

Tags: solr

We are indexing a word document in Solr. It indexed properly. However, if I search for a word which is at a position more than 11000, the search is not returning anything. Is there any configuration to make Solr search work on entire data in the document indexed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Solr are you using? With version 4 there have been changes around that. If you are using Solr 4.X, could you post the analyzer of the affected field? This is to check if a `LimitTokenCountFactory` is in play.

Comment: @cheffe Thanks for your reponse.We are using Solr 3.X.And i got the issue.We configured MaxFieldLength property in SolrConfig.xml as 10000 and the indexed document contains nearly 30000 tokens.